# ORA-00904 Linq generates error in SQL query for Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework-core, ora-00904

I use EF Core for Oracle and I try to get list of entities from the `DbContext`.

I have two model classes:

```
public class CssKursyModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("KW_ID")]
    public int Kw_Id { get; set; }

    public CssTabeleKursowModel CoursesTables { get; set; }

    [Column("KW_WAL_Z_ID")]
    public int Kw_Wal_Z_Id { get; set; }

    [Column("KW_WAL_NA_ID")]
    public int Kw_Wal_Na_Id { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CssTabeleKursowModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("TK_ID")]
    public int Tk_Id { get; set; }

    [Column("TK_SYMBOL")]
    public string Tk_Symbol { get; set; }

    [Column("TK_NAZWA")]
    public string Tk_Nazwa { get; set; }
}
```

but when I try to execute this statement

```
var t = context.CssCourses.ToList();
```

it returns an exception

> ORA-00904: "s"."CoursesTablesTk_Id": invalid identifier

What can I do to resolve this situation?

When I changed my CSSKursyModel and add ForeignKey atributte, like this

```
 {
        [Key]
        [Column("KW_ID")]
        public int Kw_Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TK_ID")]
        public CssTabeleKursowModel CoursesTables { get; set; }

        [Column("KW_WAL_Z_ID")]
        public int Kw_Wal_Z_Id { get; set; }

        [Column("KW_WAL_NA_ID")]
        public int Kw_Wal_Na_Id { get; set; }
}
```

and changed method to

```
var t = context.CssCourses
                        .Include(i => i.CoursesTables.Tk_Id)
                        .ToList();
```

the error message looks like
ORA-00904: "i"."TK_ID": invalid identifier

The Column name is correct (TK_ID) but execution still ended by ORA-00904 exception

Regards

Comment: please edit the question and show the tables DDL.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle stores object (and column) names in UPPERCASE by default, unless you enclosed those names into double quotes at time of creation. Oracle people don't do that, so - if someone created the table for you, I presume they did it that way, i.e. didn't use double quotes.

In that case, you can reference column names using any letter case you want.

It means that you should try with `"COURSESTABLESTK_ID"` (if that *Linq* thing requires double quotes; I don't speak it so I can't tell). Otherwise, as far as Oracle itself is concerned, `COURSESTABLESTK_ID` (without double quotes) would do.

---

Your code would work if someone created the table as

```
create table some_table ("CoursesTablesTk_Id" number);
```

I presume that it was, actually,

```
create table some_table (CoursesTablesTk_Id number);
```

which means that

```
select coursestablestk_id from some_table
```

or

```
select COURSEStablesTk_Id from some_table
```

or

```
select COURSESTABLESTK_ID from some_table
```

would do.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is because you have on your code a field that does not exist in the database. The signature of this issue is that the query fails because you have a field referenced as "t".[tableName][FiledName]. When the entity framework is unable to map the field to an existing column on the database it creates a field like that.

To troubleshoot do the following:

1. Identify the field that is causing the problem:
   Sometimes this is difficult because of nested relationships. Try adding the [NoMapped] attribute one field at a time until the error goes away.
2. Check for typos in the field name. Sometimes you include a field as part of a relationship (like using a linked table without any referential integrity constrain) in this case will not be typo, but just a field that does not exists.

Summing Up: Your mission is to find a field in your object that is not in the table, if there is a typo, fix it, if the field does not exist in the database but you need it, add the [NoMapped] attribute.

Hope this helps.

Regards.